# Case studies of Participatory Spatial Planning

Tags: web-mapping, web-service, web-gis

I am wondering if you know any well implemented geoportals for Participatory Spatial Planning. I am looking for the one related to environmental protection or connected somehow with the topic (but of course not only- if you have any just put it here).

Comment: I looking for some kind of web-based GIS application with a discussion panel where people can exchange their opinions of planning investments. Where it can be done by adding a comments or by editing a map for a particular user. I am looking forward to see more examples. Anyway thank's for existing one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very sucessfull example is the one from Belo Horizonte's city council here in Brazil.

More details in: http://opdigital.pbh.gov.br/ (I guess it's portuguese only).

I'm currently working on a project to do this for another city council, but I can't give further details - for now :D

Comment: unfortunately in portuguese only...have you got something like this one but in eng language?

Comment: hello com, I really don't have this one on english. Google might help you out translating. sorry :(

Answer (score 5):

[MarineMap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marinemap) is a spatial planning tool for the marine environment, used to engage stakeholders in the process of planning marine protected areas.

Comment: ...and MarineMap is open source. http://code.google.com/p/marinemap/

Comment: I was looking exactly something like this one. Thank's a lot. And i am still waiting for more...

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look at [FixMyStreet](http://www.fixmystreet.com/), though not being a UK resident I couldn't tell you how well it works.

As an added bonus as well, like the above, the source code is [open source](http://github.com/mysociety/fixmystreet).

Comment: works very well.

Answer (score 2):

I found myself [this](http://www.bikenwalk.com/) project very interesting.

Another interesting projects i've found:

http://www.greenmap.org/

http://www.imrivers.org/njair/

http://www.imrivers.org/chesterriver/

http://www.communitymap.net/chatham/

http://www.communitymap.net/deer/bernards/

http://www.thewatershed.org/sourlands/index.html

http://www.camdendccb.org/

http://www.camdenresources.org/

If i will find more i will put it here.

Another portion:

http://www.ccg.leeds.ac.uk/teaching/nuclearwaste/

http://www.ppgis.manchester.ac.uk/projects/slaithwaite/